# Aligning *some* text in a <th>?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/F7BTx/

I'm trying to align just some text within a table header cell to the bottom of the cell, but I need the rest of the text to be centered. What's the best way to do this?

Ex desired output:

```
Header 1 is       Header 2           Header 3
on two lines        

    [-]              [-]                [-]
```

Current output:

```
Header 1 is       Header 2           Header 3
on two lines        

                     [-]                [-]
    [-]
```

Comment: why don't you just use two `tr`? That will do the trick

Comment: Not possible. The second elements are being added dynamically with javascript, and I'm trying to keep the markup as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use `vertical-align: bottom;` instead of `vertical-align: center;`; however this will also bring the `Header n`s to the bottom as well. There is no way around this, that I am aware of, other than to use two rows for your header. One with `th`s and one with `td`s. Vertically align the second row with `vertical-align: bottom` and the first one with `vertical-align: center;`

Comment: "Your question is not easily answered in a good way" is the best solution to this problem, unfortunately :P.

Answer (score 1):

edit: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/TKxrC/20/

Try something like this:

```
<style>
  th.cool_format {
    position:relative; height:64px;
  }
  th.cool_format .table_head_title {
    position:absolute;
  }
  th.cool_format .some_weird_thing {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
  }
</style>
<th class='cool_format'>
  <span class='table_head_title'> Header 1 is on two lines </span>
  <span class='some_weird_thing'> [-] </span>
</th>
```

...not tested. If it doesn't work right, try giving `th.cool_format` a fixed width and the stuff inside of it the same width or widths of 100%. If it still doesn't work replace the `span`s with `div`s or make the spans `display:block`.

Comment: I tried something similar. It seems you can't use relative positioning for table cells, so you need a dummy `div` inside the `th`.

Comment: yeah, you do... just realized that myself. I think it's because `th` are not `display:block`.

Comment: I don't know the heights of the headers. This is dynamic and needs to be re-usable across different table setups.

Comment: Post that as an answer, no. Either way, it doesn't work in IE or Opera :P. Didn't try chrome.

Comment: If it didn't help it's not a very good answer ;) ... actually this can work or not work depending on your doctype; heights in standards mode can be very counterintuitive. Google "doctype height css" or "css table height" or something along those lines and you'll see what I mean. This article looks decent at a glance -- http://apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php

Comment: There's no way in hell I can get a DOCTYPE change in right now. I'm dealing with a legacy application, and a doctype change (to <!DOCTYPE html>) is at least 2 years away.